# Match a substring, ignoring a list of words and special characters

Tags: regex

I have phrases of 1 or more words that I need to match against some text. The special characters have to be ignored, and there is a small list of words (~20) that should also be ignored.

Example:

phrase - "cat fish";

ignore words - "likes"

- "There is a **cat fish**." - **True**
- "There is a **cat, fish** and a dog." - **True** (punctuation "," ignored)
- "My **cat *likes* fish** very much." - **True** (special word ignored)
- "My **cat *likes*)- fish** very much." - **True** (punctuation and special word ignored)
- "My cat likes and eats fish a lot." - **False**

I have a list of "special" words that are optional and should be ignored ("likes" from e.g.)

I tried with regex but can't seem to handle the special characters

`\b(cat)(\s|likes)(fish)\b`

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/AlhWUX/1) working for you?

Comment: Does `"cat fish"` need to be separated by at least 1 space?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano yes, there has to be a space. Thank you for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily capture the special characters by the negative form `[^\w]`. Try this:

```
\bcat\b[^\w]*(?:likes)?[^\w]*\bfish\b
```

Or if you want to match any number of the word `"likes"` e.g. `"My cat likeslikeslikes   -+)) likes fish very much."`:

```
\bcat\b(?:[^\w]|likes)*\bfish\b
```

Or if you want to match any number of the word `"likes"` but must be separated by space or special characters e.g. `"My cat likes likes-likes   -+)) likes fish very much."`:

```
\bcat\b(?:[^\w]|\blikes\b)*\bfish\b
```

**Sample Run**
[image]

Where:

- `\bcat\b` - Match "cat" surrounded by word boundaries
- `(?:[^\w]|\blikes\b)*` - Optionally, match either:

  - Any special characters
  - The word "likes" surrounded by word boundaries
- `\bfish\b` - Match "fish" surrounded by word boundaries

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for pointing out :) I updated the answer.

Comment: I went for the second suggestion ( \bcat(?:[^\w]|likes)*fish\b ), but how do I modify it to require a "space" if there is more than 1 "likes"?

Comment: @MiroslavGeorgiev you can just add the word boundary `\b` to require the spaces. I updated my answer, could you check if it works on your side?

Comment: yes, it works! I actually modified it a bit, because there is a problem with underscore(`"_"`). I also added a couple more "ignore" words.
`(\b|_)cat(\b|_)(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]|(\b|_)wants(\b|_)|(\b|_)likes(\b|_)|(\b|_)eats(\b|_))*(\b|_)fish(\b|_)`
Do you think that is a good approach to ignore `"_"`?